# UITableView doesn't refresh on iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession

My pull to refresh feature actually work, but doesn't reload the data. If I close and open the app I can reach the data, but I couldn't load the data if I use pull to refresh.

```
var page : Int = 1
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        refresher = UIRefreshControl()

        refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newPollsTableViewController.refresh), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

        self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)

            data_request() 
}
```

this is my data_request() func:

```
func data_request(){
    let user_id = Data[0].valueForKey("user_id") as? String!

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://..../perspective/\(user_id!)/page/"+"\(page)" )!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    self.page = self.page + 1


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        var json: AnyObject?

        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
        } 
        catch {
            return
        }

        guard let data_array = json as? NSArray else {
            return
        }

        for i in 0..<data_array.count
        {
            if let add = data_array[i] as? NSDictionary
            {   
                self.obj.append(Obj(data:add))
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in   
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
     }
    task.resume()  
}
```

and I call the my refresh func when I pull the refresh the table.

```
func refresh() {
        self.page = 1
        data_request()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
}
```

each time I pull the refresh the table it enters the data_request() func but it doesn't update the table.

Comment: Does your code reach the call to `reloadData` or does it hit one of the `return` statements?

Comment: @rmaddy it reaches the reloadData

Comment: What happens if you remove the `() -> Void` ?

Comment: So your code reaching `reloadData` but data is not reloaded?

Comment: Yes, but after closing and opening the app data shown

Comment: I realize that actually it gets the data but doesn't put it to the firs cell of the table @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

```
data_request()
self.refresher.endRefreshing()
```

`data_request` is asynchronous method and it returns almost immediately. So you end refreshing *before* data is actually loaded.

What you should probably do is to move `endRefreshing` call into data task completion closure. Make sure you call it on main queue.

Comment: Are you saying call the endRefreshing after the reloadData? I tried that also but it didn't work too

Comment: I suggest put it right after this line : `(let data, let response, let error) in`

Comment: I realize that actually it gets the data but doesn't put it to the firs cell of the table @rmaddy